# Android Foursquare display

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I want to know which type of layout Foursquare use to display like that? I'm not mistaken, they are not using ListView. Actually, they will use other view like TableView or something else. Please let me know if you know about that.

Comment: Looks like a list view to me. It's probably highly customised...

Comment: What I really want to know is "space" between blocks. It's really interesting.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve positioning or views in Android dev, Anup's answer seems good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just one view. It can be many views.

My guess would be a parent RelativeLayout with multiple child LinearLayouts or Relative Layouts with multiple elements inside them such as ImageViews, TextViews etc. The whole thing is probably wrapped in fragments and controlled via the action bar at the top.

This is again just a guess as there are many great ways to achieve this UI depending on what kind of devices you are targeting, optimization requirements etc.